# How do I loop through an xmlhttprequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to pull a set of cells from a google spreadsheet into a webpage for reporting.  I read a few other posts which suggested using a timeout but I cannot seem to get that working either.  If you think that would work, I can add my code that I tried to use for the timeout.  Here is my code:

```
    var days = new Array(); 
days[0] ="G11%3AG11"; /*Today*/
days[1] ="G10%3AG10";
days[2] ="G9%3AG9";
days[3] ="G8%3AG8";
days[4] ="G7%3AG7";
days[5] ="G6%3AG6";
days[6] ="G5%3AG5";
days[7] ="G4%3AG4"; /*One week ago*/

    var dayOfWeek = new Array();    
dayOfWeek[0] ="day0";
dayOfWeek[1] ="day1";
dayOfWeek[2] ="day2";
dayOfWeek[3] ="day3";
dayOfWeek[4] ="day4";
dayOfWeek[5] ="day5";
dayOfWeek[6] ="day6";
dayOfWeek[7] ="day7";

    function getValue(cell, element){
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=MyKey&single=true&gid=2&range="+cell+"&output=csv";
temp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        temp.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (temp.readyState === 4) {
              document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = temp.responseText;
          }
      };
      temp.open("GET", url, true);
      temp.send(null);
```

}

When I call the function in the main body of the code this is what it looks like:

```
    for(var a=0;a<days.length;a++){      
     getValue(days[a],dayOfWeek[a]);
    }
```

When I run it in a for loop I get the same value for each of my id tags.  They are all the value from the last item in the array.  I am not sure if the issue is with the xmlhttprequest not getting enough time or what, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your loop declares an index `a` yet you reference `i` in the body?  Also you should really consider making a single request for data pertaining to each day rather than 7 concurrently as this will inevitably be the start of a bottleneck when you do get your code working.

Comment: Good catch @Emissary thanks!  Eventually we will switch to pulling all 7 days but this was simpler to get the project up and running for the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not properly declaring "temp" as a local variable in the XHR event handler.  Add `var` in front of it.  Without that, it's global. That means that each call to "getValue()" overwrites the work of the previous one.